# Why my WCF Client references (base on task), generated xxxxxResponse?

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    GetServerDatetimeCallback GetServerDatetime();
}
```

WCF Service:

```
public class ServerService : IServerService
{

    public GetServerDatetimeCallback GetServerDatetime()
    {
        GetServerDatetimeCallback callback = new GetServerDatetimeCallback();
        try
        {
            callback.ServerDatetime = DateTime.Now;
            callback.Result = 1;
            return callback;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            callback.Result = 255;
            return callback;
        }
    }
}
```

Client Settings:

ServiceAddress: 'net.tcp://localhost:50011/ServerService/mex'
Options: 'Allow generation of asynchronous operations' - checked, 'Generate task-based operations' - selected

Client call WCF Code:

```
private ServerServiceClient client = new ServerServiceClient();

public async Task<GetServerDatetimeCallback> GetServerDatetimeAsync()
{
    return await client.GetServerDatetimeAsync();
}
```

Usually i call a wcf function async like this, and always worked fine.
but today i do it again in a new project, i found the 'await client.GetServerDatetimeAsync();' returns no longer 'GetServerDatetimeCallback' object, but a 'GetServerDatetimeResponse'.

how this happen?

**UPDATED GetServerDatetimeCallback object**

```
[DataContract]
public class GetServerDatetimeCallback
{
    [DataMember]
    public byte Result { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime ServerDatetime { get; set; }
}
```

**And this is Service Reference generated**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetServerDatetimeResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetServerDatetimeResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public ServerServiceObjects.GetServerDatetimeCallback GetServerDatetimeResult;

    public GetServerDatetimeResponse() {
    }

    public GetServerDatetimeResponse(ServerServiceObjects.GetServerDatetimeCallback GetServerDatetimeResult) {
        this.GetServerDatetimeResult = GetServerDatetimeResult;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it generated a System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute but not a System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute?

Comment: "... in a new project,..." Most likely it has to do with the way you did the "Add Servicereference".  It has several options for code generation.

Comment: I did the same thing as previous projects. 1. Add Service Reference; 2. provide service address; 3. provide a namespace; 4. click ok; It will automatic generate task-base functions for me. But this time, task-based return value became 'xxxResponse'...

Comment: OK, better question this way but I still have no clue. Try to reproduce it (again) in a small throw-away app. Pay close attention to all settings and versions.